# How to use both Google Drive API and the chrome web payments licensing API

Tags: php, google-docs-api, google-drive-api, chrome-web-store

UPDATE to clarify the question...

In attempting google drive example app Dr edit for php working in our test app which had already successfully implemented the licensing API, https://developers.google.com/chrome/web-store/docs/samples#php, we got an 'error saving' message and a syntax error from dredit.js trying to log error to console.

We realized that we needed to update the existing apps manifest.json with some needed info, setting the CONTAINER  to GOOGLE_DRIVE and the id from API console.

However, that brought a warning from developer dashboard that made us sad because it seems our task is not possible:

> - Apps that specify a container other than CHROME in the manifest may not use Chrome Web Store payments.

Catch22: Use CHROME (apparently the default) or GOOGLE_DRIVE for container?

So that's our question: We want to incorporate the drive AND chrome web store payments in php and I am not sure how the tutorials for drive and licensing API can be reconciled regarding container.   Did we fail to read that GDrive enabled apps must be free?

NOTE: Making it more complicated is the fact that it seems lots of solutions to access docs via the documents-list-API are deprecated now, for instance authsub and oauth 1.0 solutions.  Ideally, we wouldn't want to write a web app that stops working in 2015.

Comment: To see a bit of what was in the console log, see my previous edits.

Comment: We reviewed this in the Google Drive SDK office hours, and have decided that this is a bug.  Thanks for reporting, we'll get this taken care of, so that this error doesn't show when using GOOGLE_DRIVE.  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, it's great that Google is on SO now!  Perhaps you can let us know can we track the status of the bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Google Drive API is brand new at this time.  Google has decided this is a bug and will be fixing the issue.  Thanks folks!

Until then, we can charge for our app and access the same data via the documents list api.

Comment: I'm sure there are more discussions going on about how to further streamline how all of the many Google API's interact.  For now, this is a known bug.