# Monetization of a Google Drive App

Tags: google-drive-api, chrome-web-store

I created an web app that uses the Google Drive SDK.  I followed the instructions of how to get listed in the Chrome Web Store including using the following format for the manifest file

```
{
  "name" : "DrEdit",
  "version" : "2",
  "description" : "Text editor",
  "container" : "GOOGLE_DRIVE",
  "api_console_project_id" : "[[YOUR_API_PROJECT_ID]]",
  "icons": {
    "128": "icon-128.png"
  },
  "app" : {
    "launch" : {
      "web_url" : "[[YOUR_WEB_APP_URL]]"
    }
  }
}
```

however when I try to set the pricing in the Chrome Store Developer Dashboard, I get an error saying

> Apps that specify a container other than CHROME in the manifest may
>   not use Chrome Web Store payments.

Is it not possible to use Google Checkout with Drive Apps?

Comment: A similar question has been asked a while ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10543483/how-to-use-both-google-drive-api-and-the-chrome-web-payments-licensing-api While it's theoretically possible, it seems like the current behavior is a bug. I'm raising an issue.

Comment: @Burcu. Thanks. That other post seems to show that this "Bug" was already reported internally at Google last year.  Is there a public list of such bugs...I am trying to get another one on the list...see this item http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15777577/issue-with-google-drive-api-call-when-searching-for-a-file

Comment: With regards to this "bug" is there a public list of issues (perhaps that can be up-voted).